# Generate Dynamic Form from XSD

Tags: xml, forms, xsd

I'm in the process of creating a web service that uses XML to handle information transfers between client(s) and the server. I've defined an XSD for the service and now need to come up with a really simple way for non technical users to quickly create test XML documents. Hence, I was wondering if people could explain what the best practices to do this would be and if anyone had suggestion for software to look into that can take an XSD and create a dynamic form non-technical users could fill out and save the result as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on my own project called XsdFormEditor. Application will be able to show any XSD as a form in WinForms (95% done), Web (using Asp.Net MVC, 0% done), WPF (0% done). Idea is to load any XSD file, show it to user as a form, let user input some data and save data as XML. User will be also able to load default values to form from XML file. You can find it here: https://github.com/janstafa/XsdFormEditor